# I want to populate XML tags on the basis of JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, mxgraph

I have a sample JSON object. I want to show that in XML in a file dynamically i.e., whenever I update my JSON object the XML code should automatically be updated through jQuery.

Here is my sample JSON object:

```
[{
    "reporting": "purchase",
    "Name": "3",
    "designation": "ert"
},

{
    "reporting": "quality",
    "Name": "4",
    "designation": "yui"
},
```

]

I'm using jQuery to update this.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sample.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        $.each(res, function (i, val) { 
            console.log(val['reporting']);
            $("Array").find("add").each(function (u) { 
                console.log(u);
            })
        });
    }
});
```

In the XML code, I want to update this in  and  that reporting value from JSON object. The XML code which I want to update is in `<add as="<----reporting value from JSON---->">` and also in  as `<add as="<----reporting value from JSON---->">`:

```
<Array as="templates">
    <add as="purchase">
        <Roundrect label="Purchase" href="">
            <mxCell vertex="1" style="rounded">     
                <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="80" height="40"/>
            </mxCell>
        </Roundrect>
    </add>
    <add as="quality">
        <Roundrect label="Quality" href="">
            <mxCell vertex="1" style="rounded">     
                <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="80" height="40"/>
            </mxCell>
        </Roundrect>
    </add>
<Array>
<mxDefaultToolbar as="toolbar">
    <add as="quality" template="quality" icon="images/rounded.gif"/>
    <add as="purchase" template="purchase" icon="images/rounded.gif"/>
</mxDefaultToolbar>
```

Comment: Hi, which value you need to update ? Please can you add final op as well.

Comment: I want to update `<add as="purchase">` where purchase is fetched from JSON object. Also, I am using jquery code to update this in XML file. So, I have to call sample.json file and XML file simultaneoulsy.

Comment: Okay what value should be there instead of `<add as="purchase">` ? It would easy if you can let us know final op you need .

Comment: This value should be updated dynamically from server. In the place of purchase there can be anything which takes the value of "reporting" in JSON object. The tag is appended in XML in ajax call from JSON object. Whenever value is added to JSON in "reporting", then `<add>` is generated with "as" as value of "reporting".

Comment: Hi , you need something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/fas92e4t/5/) ?

Comment: You were somewhat correct but this will not work because I want to add data(which I got from "reporting" key of JSON) to XML. And the way which you have shown is applicable to HTML not XML. The `$("Array").find("add").eq(i).attr("as",val['reporting'])` concept is correct but its better for understanding. But not applicable to XML. Because you cannot directly interact with XML through jquery. First, you need to convert XML to JSON through jquery and then apply something to it.

Comment: Can you create json structure same as XML structure? if yes then you can convert js object to XML directly instead placing particular values. The other possible solution is to convert xml to js object, loop through, replace values, and then convert it back to xml.

Answer (score 0):

Guess all you need are some string concatinations, in my example I show you using template strings and arrow functions. but you can also use traditional strings:

```js
var res = [{
    "reporting": "purchase",
    "Name": "3",
    "designation": "ert"
  },
  {
    "reporting": "quality",
    "Name": "4",
    "designation": "yui"
  }
];
var xml = `<Array as="templates">
  ${res.map(value=>`
  <add as="${value.reporting}">
    <Roundrect label="${value.reporting[0].toUpperCase()}${value.reporting.substr(1)}" href="">
      <mxCell vertex="1" style="rounded">
        <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="80" height="40"/>
      </mxCell>
    </Roundrect>
  </add>
  `).join('')}
<Array>
<mxDefaultToolbar as="toolbar">
    <add as="quality" template="quality" icon="images/rounded.gif"/>
    <add as="purchase" template="purchase" icon="images/rounded.gif"/>
</mxDefaultToolbar>`;
```

note: there is no general way to translate json objects into xml, because you have to make many decisions along the way such as:

- Are props becoming attributes or child elements, ?
- do you need nice formatting?
- your xml has some more custom elements
- ...

And feel free to put the string creation into its own function.